# Best data structure for a given set of operations - Add, Retrieve Min/Max and Retrieve a specific object

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for the optimal (time and space) optimal data structure for supporting the following operations:

1. Add Persons (**name, age**) to a global data store of persons
2. Fetch Person with minimum and maximum age
3. Search for Person's **age** given the **name**

Here's what I could think of:

- Keep an array of Persons, and keep adding to end of array when a new Person is to be added
- Keep a hash of Person name vs. age, to assist in fetching person's age with given name
- Maintain two objects minPerson and maxPerson for Person with min and max age. Update this if needed, when a new Person is added.

Now, although I keep a hash for better performance of (3), I think it may not be the best way if there are many collisions in the hash. Also, addition of a Person would mean an overhead of adding to the hash.

Is there anything that can be further optimized here?

**Note: I am looking for the best (balanced) approach to support all these operations in minimum time and space.**

Comment: There is no need for the array. Just the hash + min and max should work. Note that structure like this doesn't support removing from it, because that might invalidate the min or max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you need a data structure that needs fast inserts and that also supports fast queries on 2 different keys (name and age).

I would suggest keeping two data structures, one a sorted data structure (e.g. a balanced binary search tree) where the key is the age and the value is a pointer to the Person object, the other a hashtable where the key is the name and the value is a pointer to the Person object. Notice we don't keep two copies of the same object.

A balanced binary search tree would provide O(log(n)) inserts and max/min queries, while the hastable would give us O(1) (amortized) inserts and lookups.

When we add a new Person, we just add a pointer to it to both data structures. For a min/max age query, we can retrieve the Object by querying the BST. For a name query we can just query the hashtable.

Your question does not ask for updates/deletes, but those are also doable by suitably updating both data structures.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the array as it doesn't provide anything that the other two structures can't do.

Otherwise, a hashtable + min/max is likely to perform well for your use case. In fact, this is precisely what I would use.

As to getting rid of the hashtable because a poor hash function might lead to collisions: well, don't use a poor hash function. I bet that the default hash function for strings that's provided by your programming language of choice is going to do pretty well out of the box.

Comment: yes, if I go with the hash table, the array is not necessary. but I feel the hash needs to be done away with altogether - but am not sure what would best replace it.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the hash table?  Hash tables are one of the best data structures in all of software engineering.  Don't worry; nobody is going to give 100,000 children weird names in an attempt to attack your hash function.

Comment: @Saket - why would you want to get rid of the hash table?  Hash tables perform extremely well for this task.

Comment: I am just thinking if I could **avoid** it. I understand its one of the best options (hence, am having a tough time thinking of a different approach :)). I'm actually looking for the best (balanced) way out for all these operations. Fine with me, if my solution already sounds (close to) perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting the name to be the unique idenitifer; otherwise your operation 3 is ambiguous (What is the correct return result if you have two entries for John Smith?)

Assuming that the uniqueness of a name is guaranteed, I would go with a plain hashtable keyed by names.  Operation 1 and 3 are trivial to execute.  Operation 2 could be done in O(N) time if you want to search through the data structure manually, or you can do like you suggest and keep track of the min/max and update it as you add/delete entries in the hash table.